# Migration from attr_encrypted to vault-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

Earlier my code was having encryption methodology using 'attr_encrypted' but later I changed my mind to integrate vault for encryption/decryption. So I want to understand how can I migrate my old saved encrypted data to new one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward. If you have, say, field `ssn`

```
attr_encrypted :ssn
```

You can create a second field, now backed by vault

```
vault_attribute :ssn2
```

Then iterate your records and set `ssn2` value to that of `ssn`. This should take care of data migration.

After that is done, you might want to delete ssn's backing fields and rename ssn2's backing field(s), so that rest of your code continues to use name `ssn`.

Comment: Need a bit correction, I want to use both the mechanism, if someone data is already saved using attr_encrypted then use that and vault for new user or any old user is updating their data.

Comment: @RahulTibrewal: that's a different question.

Comment: I have added a new question, can you please have a look on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498689/upgrading-from-attr-encrypted-and-vault-rails-for-same-key