# Upgrading from attr_encrypted and Vault-rails for same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

I was using `attr_encrypted` mechanism previously,

```
attr_encrypted :ssn, key: :encryption_key, algorithm: 'bf-cfb', mode: :single_iv_and_salt, insecure_mode: true
```

and I upgraded it to `vault-rails`:

```
include Vault::EncryptedModel
vault_attribute :ssn
```

I want to keep both in a way that, if some data is already saved using `attr_encrypted` then use that, and use vault for new user or if any old user is updating their data.

Comment: Does that work? These accessors will overwrite each other

Comment: Why not upgrade all users at once and be done with it?

Comment: That's a good option but its huge amount of data.

Comment: Well then, create two encrypted properties (legacy `ssn` and new `ssn2`, for example) and choose between them at runtime. Based on a user's flag `use_vault_key?` or something like that. But I'd try the full migration if I were you. Why create this complication when you can simply do something to not need it.